how to Retry/ok skip in samsung android phone default application
y project is an application that uses the default android phone camera application to take a picture and save it with a watermark , but the retry / ok selector after capturing the image is annoying and is not user friendly at all . here is my method :
private Uri saveImageToGallery(Bitmap bitmap) {
        OutputStream fos;
        Uri imageUri = null;
        try {
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, "captured_image_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

                imageUri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
                fos = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(imageUri);
            } else {
                String imagesDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString();
                File image = new File(imagesDir, "captured_image_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
                fos = new FileOutputStream(image);
                imageUri = Uri.fromFile(image);
            }

            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();

            Toast.makeText(this, "Image saved to gallery", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to save image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        return imageUri;
    }


What part of this code causes "the retry / ok selector" to appear?

Mostly media store part
